# What happens when doing testing inside RStudio?

Tags: r, debugging, environment, testthat

The bug I am getting take some setting up. But here I will try to explain the issue to be reproducible.

Create a test file within the `./test/testhat` directory called `test-for-bugs.r` and in that file put

```
test_that("testing", {
  library(disk.frame)
  setup_disk.frame()
  test_df = as.disk.frame(cars, nchunks = 2)
  test_result = test_df %>%
    group_by(!!!syms(names(test_df))) %>%
    summarize(n=n()) %>% 
    collect
})
```

Now just click the Run Tests button in [rstudio](/questions/tagged/rstudio)

[image]

then you would see this error

> ````
> test-for-fun.r:6: error: testing object 'test_df' not found Backtrace:
>   1. dplyr::group_by(., !!!syms(names(test_df)))
>   1. dplyr::summarize(., n = n())
>   9. dplyr::collect(.)
>  11. disk.frame::chunk_group_by(., !!!syms(names(test_df)))
>  28. rlang:::map(x, sym)
>  29. base::lapply(.x, .f, ...) ```
> ````

However, if you run the same code in the `REPL` line by line then the error doesn't appear. Also, from the command line `Rscript test-for-fun.r` also works flawlessly.

**What's different about the [r](/questions/tagged/r) environment when running tests?**

Thanks...

Comment: Is cars preloaded in your environment via an earlier command? Maybe testing uses a fresh environment without any pre-loaded libraries and datasets. Try changing your code to include an explicit import of cars.

Comment: No need to be rude. Yes cars is readily available in normal Rstudio environment and as you yourself pointed out the code runs normally. However in testing there is a clear error in finding the df which could come down to how testing treats preloaded datasets even if they are part of base. So unless you know for a fact, this is not the problem (which you could mention in your question), I think it's off base to insult a helpful comment which I did not offer as an answer knowing it was a shot in the dark.